# How to check if a response packet is received within a particular time limit?

Tags: java, timer, timertask, datagram

Suppose a client sends server a request. The server responds with an ACK. However, if the server does not respond within two seconds, the code terminates.

```
socket.receive(ack);
```

is a blocking call. However, I assumed that if I disconnected the socket in timer task, this blocking call will be ignored now and the code will continue. But it still acts as a blocking call, so this code does not function the way I want it to. Is there some other way to implement the same thing?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timeout = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

socket.send(request);
timer.schedule(timeout, 2000);
socket.receive(ack);

String data = new String(ack.getData());
if ((data.substring(0,3)).equals("ACK")) {
    received = true;
    timer.cancel();
}

if (received) {
    //rest of the code
}
else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Check out the [Documentation of `DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `Timer` object. You can set the timeout in the socket and catch the potential timeout exception to handle the closing / termination of the program.

```
socket.send(request);
socket.setSoTimeout(20000);
try {
    socket.receive(ack);
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to set **SOCKET TIMEOUT** like this:
It is timeout for incoming data:

```
Socket s = new Socket(address, port);
s.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

You can also set a connection timeout if you can't connect with server in some resonable time:

```
s.connect(endpoint, timeout)
```

it will throw an TimeoutException after timeout time, and break the blocking execution;